# Верстка: Float'ы или Flex'ы?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Я новичок во фронтенде, изучаю вопрос создания сайта с нуля. 
Последнее время буквально мучает вопрос, что считают бывалые в этом деле насчет верстки сайта целиком на флексах (flex)? Вроде как и резина реализуется, и адаптив одновременно. Или же первые попытки лучше делать по старинке ДИВами и их размещать флоатами? Какая техника предпочтительнее?

P.S. Разумеется, надо попробовать и то и то самому и решить, но хотелось бы некой конкретики по этому поводу.

Comment: Если Ваш вопрос закроют или же не получите качественного ответа, попробуйте также задать его [**здесь**](http://ux.stackexchange.com/). Спасибо.

Answer (score 13):

Однозначно стоит изучать flexbox в первую очередь.

Единственные доводы в сторону `float`:

1. старые браузеры (IE9-).
2. поддержка и понимание работы существующего кода (на данный момент  существует действительно очень много кода, использующего `float`).

---

#### Принципиальные различия

Они принципиально отличаются. `float` присваивается элементами, а `display: flex` или `display: inline-flex;` присваивается контейнерам и оказывают влияние на расположение элементов контейнера. Когда блоку присвоен `display: flex` или `display: inline-flex;`, его элементы игнорируют свойства `float`, `clear` и `vertical-align`.

#### Предостережение

Собираюсь сравнивать flexbox и `float` на небольшом подмножестве возможностей flexbox на котором они сравнимы. Скажу сразу, что не рассмотрены или рассмотрены вскользь такие аспекты работы flexbox (которые невоплотимы через `float`, кроме *некоторых случаев* многострочной разметки):

- многострочная разметки (когда элементы могут разрастаться на несколько строк). Достигается через установку контейнеру `flex-wrap: wrap;` или `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;`. Через `float` элементы разве что могут располагаться по левому краю (через float: left;) либо просто по правому краю (через `float: right`) с *необходимостью инвертировать порядок расположения элементов*. Отдельная большая тем для flexbox из-за его огромных возможностей.
- расположение элементов в стоблец (когда элементы располагаются не в строчку). Достигается через установку контейнеру `flex-direction: column;` или `flex-direction: column-reverse;`. Отдельная большая тема для flexbox из-за его огромных возможностей.
- возможности flex-элементов растягиваться и сужаться с помощью свойств `flex-grow` и `flex-shrink`. Советую детально изучить эту непростую тему.
- как flex-элементы работают с `margin: auto;` (`margin` занимает оставшееся пространство в соответствующем направлении).
- сочетание flexbox и абсолютного позиционирования.
- взаимодействие flexbox-элементов c отрицательными `margin` и `z-index` (можно регулировать кто-то на кого "залазит" без абсолютного позиционирования).

  Установим положительный `z-index` для первого элемента, что он "залазил" на второй (если уберём — то будет наоборот):

  ```css
  .flex {
    display: flex;
  }

  .flex-item {
    /* Просто для демонстрации */
    color: white;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .flex-item:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    /* Зададим чтобы первый "налазил" на второй */
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .flex-item:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: lime;
    margin-left: -20px;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="flex-item">
      One
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      Two
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- flexbox и таблицы. Можно `tr` установить `display: flex;` и получить адаптивность для строк таблицы. Например мы можем инвертировать расположение элементов в строках таблицы:

  ```css
  tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }

  td {
    border: 1px solid gray;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1-1</td>
      <td>1-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2-1</td>
      <td>2-2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  ```

#### Чем float плох? Чем flexbox хорош?

Предполагается, что рассматириваем распложение элементов в строчку. При расположении в столбец некоторые приведенные ниже свойства будут работать по-другому.

1. Чтобы контейнер имел ненулевую высоту ему приходится всегда добавлять класс `clearfix`:

   ```
   .clearfix:after {
     content: "";
     display: table;
     clear: both;
   }
   ```

[image: clearfix]

Для flexbox-контейнера такие "фокусы" не нужны.

2. Нельзя горизонтально центрировать элементы с помощью `float`. Нет значения `float: center;`. Приходится применять другие приёмы.

   Для flexbox-контейнера достаточно присвоить `justify-content: center;`.

   ```css
   .container {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
   }

   .item {
     /* Просто для демонстрации */
     background-color: orange;
     color: white;
     font-size: 2rem;
     padding: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="container">
     <div class="item">
       One
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       Two
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       Three
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       Four
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       Five
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
3. Чтобы расположить элементы по правую сторону, нужно их инвертировать в разметке (расположить в обратном порядке), присвоив им `float: right;`.

   Для flexbox-контейнера достаточно присвоить `justify-content: flex-end;` и нет необходимости располагать разметку в обратном порядке.

   Демонстрация:

   ```css
   .container {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: flex-end;
   }

   .item {
     /* Просто для демонстрации */
     background-color: orange;
     color: white;
     font-size: 2rem;
     padding: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="container">
     <div class="item">
       One
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       Two
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       Three
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       Four
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       Five
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
4. Нет никакого способа менять расположение элементов, не меняя разметку.

   С помощью flexbox можно либо инвертировать расположение элементов с помощью присвоения контейнеру `flex-direction: row-reverse;`:

   ```css
   .container {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row-reverse;
   }

   .item {
     /* Просто для демонстрации */
     background-color: orange;
     color: white;
     font-size: 2rem;
     padding: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="container">
     <div class="item">
       One
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       Two
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       Three
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       Four
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       Five
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

   Также можно менять порядок индивидуальных элементов с помощью свойства `order`.

   ```css
   .container {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row-reverse;
   }

   .item {
     /* Просто для демонстрации */
     background-color: orange;
     color: white;
     font-size: 2rem;
     padding: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
   }

   .item:nth-of-type(1) { order: 3; }
   .item:nth-of-type(2) { order: 4; }
   .item:nth-of-type(3) { order: 1; }
   .item:nth-of-type(4) { order: 5; }
   .item:nth-of-type(5) { order: 2; }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="container">
     <div class="item">
       One
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       Two
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       Three
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       Four
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       Five
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
5. С помощью `float` невозможно *без хаков* гарантировать нахождение элементов на одной строке.

   В flexbox такое поведение заложено по умолчанию (`flex-wrap: nowrap;` установлено по умолчанию) и элементы не буду переноситься на новую строку без явного указания контейнеру `flex-wrap: wrap;` (или в редком случае `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;`).
6. Нет никакого контроля за вертикальным расположением элементов. Всё выравнивается "по верху" без возможности на это повлиять. Также нельзя установить элементам одинаковую высоту без установления фиксированной высоты всем элементам.

   В flexbox есть возможность установить вертикальное расположение как и всем элементу, так и индивидуально элементу. Всем — устанавливаем контейнеру `align-items`, индивидуально — устанавливаем элементу `align-item`.

   Значения:

   - `stretch` (по умолчанию) — элементы занимают всю высоту контейнера.
   - `flex-start` — выравнивание элементов по верху.
   - `center` — выравнивание элементов по центру.
   - `flex-end` — выравнивание элементов по низу.
   - `baseline` — выравнивание элементов по линии шрифта.

---

В общем, как можно увидеть flexbox несопоставимо мощней и намного выразительней вёрстки прошлых версий CSS. Поэтому крайне рекомендую его тщательно изучать, так как это воздастся сторицей.

Answer (score 2):

Единственный "*недостаток*" флексов - это их [*отсутствие в IE9 и ниже*](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Но так как Вы только начинаете изучать верстку, а их доля неуклонно снижается (на данный момент - [менее 2,5%](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201510-201610-bar) на IE8 и IE9 вместе взятые), то через некоторое время проблема отсутствия флексов в браузере перейдет из области проблем разработчика в область проблем пользователя.

Перед версткой страниц `div`-ами была верстка таблицами, но Вы же не собираетесь изучать такой анахронизм. Медленно, но верно в такой анахронизм, в данный момент, превращается верстка на `div`-ах. Поэтому целесообразнее вкладывать большую часть усилий в изучение флекс-ов, с расчетом на будущее. Если же поддержка древних браузеров будет необходима, то для них существуют различные костыли.

Но верстку на `div`-ах тоже не ст**о**ит полностью исключать, так как, будучи профессиональным разработчиком, Вы непременно столкнетесь с кучей готовых проектов, которые нужно будет то немного подправить, то слегка улучшить. Тут некоторый опыт по `div`-ам и пригодится.

Comment: Будущее за гридами, а флекс создавался не для этого... Но это почти не мешает его так использовать.

Comment: @Qwertiy неплохая [статья (*на англ*)](https://css-tricks.com/things-ive-learned-css-grid-layout/) о том, что грид - не замена флекс-ам, а дополнения друг к другу

Comment: @ZoltanToth Ваш вопрос содержит неверные сведенья. Таблицы — не анахронизм, а прекрасно подходит для вёрстки *именно* таблиц, кстати она никак не противоречит flexbox. И замены таблицам пока нет.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Вадим, Вы меня неверно поняли. Я назвал анахронизмом не таблицы, а верстку таблицами. Понятно, что для верстки таблиц нет ничего лучше элемента, который именно для этого и создавался. Но верстать страницы целиком (или их части) таблицами - вот это анахронизм.

Comment: @ZoltanToth Хорошо, но 1. Вёрстку таблицами **полезно** знать чтобы создавать таблицы. А у вас написано: "но Вы же не собираетесь изучать такой анахронизм." 2. Полезно знать по тому же доводу, что и `float`: *"Вы непременно столкнетесь с кучей готовых проектов, которые нужно будет то немного подправить"*. Так как многое лучше всего по старинке делалось именно так (самый простой пример — вертикальное центрирование). И это лучше чем хаки с абсолютом.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Вы вырвали слова из контекста. Прочитайте внимательно - "*Перед **версткой страниц** div-ами была верстка таблицами*" Я говорю *именно* о верстке страниц таблицами, а не верстке таблиц. Не таблицы анахронизм, а **верстка страниц таблицами**

Comment: @ZoltanToth Просто мысль про таблицы сформулирована неудачно. Таблицы изучать следует для таблиц. Но из вашего ответа может возникнуть ощущение, что это совсем глупо их изучать. Но у вас нету про это оговорки именно в ответе.